# Equation system

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

Hello people I've got some problems to solve this equation

$$
|f(x)| - |g(x)| + |h(x)| = 
\begin{cases}
-1  &\text{if }  x < -1 \\
3x + 2 &\text{if } -1 < x <0 \\
-2x + 2 &\text{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to solve the system but I'm stuck, so I'm counting on you for help me thanks.

PS: I'm looking for web ressources in order to improve myself in math if you have an idea do not heasitate.

Comment: I'm not sure what *solution* means for your Question.  It doesn't seem to mean "solve a system of equations" for $x$ as an unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Let
  $
\displaystyle\,
k(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-1  &\text{if }  x < -1 \\
3x + 2 &\text{if } -1 < x <0 \\
-2x + 2 &\text{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
\,$
  and define  $\,\begin{cases}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(k(x) + |k(x)|\big) \\ g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(k(x) - |k(x)|\big) \\ h(x)=0 \end{cases}\,$ 
then show that:

- $f(x) \ge 0$
- $g(x) \le 0$
- $|f(x)| - |g(x)| + |h(x)| = f(x) + g(x) = k(x)$

P.S. To the OP, if this is not the kind of answer you were looking for, please clarify the question.